# How to count how many times I move my finger on screen with touchevent in Android

Tags: android, android-touch-event

I want to count and display on textView how many times I move my finger on the screen I used the following but it counts how many times coordinates have changed

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
i++;
txtMoves.setText(String.valueOf(i));
break;
```

Comment: The coordinates will change when you move your finger .... so what's the problem???

Comment: then what you need ?? what should be get counted ?? **Move itself means Changing of co ordinates**.

Comment: How many times I moved my finger not the change of coordinates

Comment: change of co ordinates means you have moved your finger. not with a major stroke but just a little bit. If you don't move your finger co-ordinates will not be changed.!!

Comment: Action Down Action Move  from Point A to Point B this is 1 move not 55 as my code says :)

Comment: move can be of (0,1) to (0,2) and (0,0) to (100,100). Its depends on CPU how many times ACTION.MOVE gets called. **Its not that 1 co-ordinate difference is one move**. Read this :https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

Comment: Conclusion  we cannot count how many times we moved our finger ?

Comment: Conclusion : You are not getting the exact meaning of ACTION.Move.

Comment: If he measure the time he touched a specific point(x,y) and count these points?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and then `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` so you need to make some sort of state machine. If you just check for `ACTION_DOWN` you will also count clicks.